# React: How to combine multiple external makestyle using material ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have multiple external makestyle that I want to combine. So, I can organize the style per component. The single makestyle is also good but the length of the file is too much.

I saw this on material ui documentation but it's not working

```
Makestyle
import useStyles from '../styles/style';
import useAddTaskStyles from '../styles/addTaskStyle';

const classes = useStyles();
const classesAddTask = useAddTaskStyles();

const className = clsx(classes, classesAddTask);


<Modal
            className={className.modalContainer}
            open={showAddTask}
            onClose={handleCloseAddTask}
            closeAfterTransition
            BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
            BackdropProps={{
              timeout: 500,
            }}
          >
            <Fade in={showAddTask}>
              <Tasks ref={useRef} />
            </Fade>
          </Modal>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import useStyles from '../styles/style';
import useAddTaskStyles from '../styles/addTaskStyle';

const classes = useStyles();
const classesAddTask = useAddTaskStyles();

<Modal
  className={`${classes.modalContainer} ${classesAddTask.modalContainer}`}
  open={showAddTask}
  onClose={handleCloseAddTask}
  closeAfterTransition
  BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
  BackdropProps={{
    timeout: 500,
  }}
>
  <Fade in={showAddTask}>
    <Tasks ref={useRef} />
  </Fade>
</Modal>;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may combine it like this

```
const className = { ...classes, ...classesAddTask }
```

Codesandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-fire-xgvz2?file=/src/App.js

For Example (creating a useStyle hook that combines all style hooks)

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles1 = makeStyles({
  red: {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }
});

const useStyles2 = makeStyles({
  blue: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
});

const useStyles = () => {
  const classes = useStyles1();
  const classes2 = useStyles2();

  return { ...classes, ...classes2 };
};

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <div className={classes.blue} style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }}>
        blue box
      </div>
      <div className={classes.red} style={{ width: "200px", height: "200px" }}>
        red box
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```